# How to remove/change separator in values in plot_ly pie chart?

Tags: r, plotly

I have asked the same question a few weeks ago, but I still can't resolve my problem so I would be very grateful for any help. I have only two values in my data frame (called "population") and they are saved without any separators [as shown on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqQ4D.jpg). And I want to prepare a pie chart using this data. But I have a problem with displaying values on chart, because they are display with "," as a thousands separator. This is my code:

```
        labels = c('Women', 'Men')
        values = c(population[1,1], population[1,2])
        numberOfAdult <- plot_ly(type='pie', labels=labels, values=values, 
                       textinfo='percent+value',
                       insidetextorientation='radial')
        numberOfAdult <- numberOfAdult %>% layout(title = "Population by sex")
```

and I upload a picture which shows my problem: [values with commas as a separators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swPsE.jpg).
I would like to change this so that the thousands separator is a space and the number displays without commas. I've tried two ways to do it, but neither works as it should. Here is my attempts:

```
# First way
labels = c('Women', 'Men')
        values = c(comma(population[1,1], format = "d", big.mark = " "),
            population[1,2])
        numberOfAdult <- plot_ly(type='pie', labels=labels, values=values, 
                       textinfo='percent+value',
                       insidetextorientation='radial')
        numberOfAdult <- numberOfAdult %>% layout(title = "Population by sex")
 
 
# Second way
labels = c('Women', 'Men')
        values = c(population[1,1], population[1,2])
        numberOfAdult <- plot_ly(type='pie', labels=labels, values=values, 
                       textinfo='percent+value',
                       insidetextorientation='radial')
        numberOfAdult <- numberOfAdult %>% layout(title = "Population by sex",
                                                separators = ' ')
```

The first way doesn't work at all, i.e. after adding the comma function nothing happens and I get the same as without this fragment (numbers still display with commas). A second way makes that percentage values are displayed with space as a separator, but numbers of men and women still with commas.
Do you know what should I do to display number values with space as a separator?

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example, that means the data you use (or example data) and a running shiny app (but only include those elements to show your problems). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `texttemplate` this could be achieved like so:

```
library(plotly)
library(scales)

labels = c('Women', 'Men')
values = c(population$population[1:2])
numberOfAdult <- plot_ly(type='pie', labels=labels, values=values, 
                         textinfo='percent+value',
                         texttemplate = paste0(number(values, big.mark = " "), "<br>%{percent}"),
                         insidetextorientation='radial')
numberOfAdult <- numberOfAdult %>% layout(title = "Population by sex")
numberOfAdult
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just define the `separators`argument in `layout`

> separators
> Parent: layout
> Type: string
> Sets the decimal and thousand separators. For example, ". " puts a '.' before decimals and a space between thousands. In English locales, dflt is ".," but other locales may alter this default.

```
labels = c('Women', 'Men')
values = c(17383905,14649394)

numberOfAdult <- plot_ly(type='pie', labels=labels, values=values, 
                         textinfo='percent+value',
                         insidetextorientation='radial')
numberOfAdult <- numberOfAdult %>% 
  layout(title = "Population by sex", separators = '. ')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!